# Continuous linear operator / Proof

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

Could someone help me with this question?

Let be $T\in{L(X,Y)}$ and $M=Ker(T)\neq{X}$ and $T^{*}:X/M\rightarrow{Y}$ the only linear operator such that $T=T^{*}\circ\pi$. Show that $ T^{*}$ is continuous.

Thanks

Comment: Who is the $\pi$ mapping?

Comment: Probably the natural epimorphism $\pi:X\rightarrow X/M,x\mapsto [x]=x+M$, where $X/M$ is equipped with the quotient space topology.

Comment: $T^*$ is defined by $T^*(x + ker\,T) := Tx$.

Comment: Yes, $\pi$ is the natural epimorphism which @PeterMelech talks about

Comment: The quotient space can be equipped with a norm $|[x]|_{X/M}=\inf_{m\in M}|x-m|_X$ that induces the quotient space topology.

Comment: And, how can we conclude that $T^{*}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $[x]=x+M$ , then $||[x]||= \inf\{||z||: z \in [x]\}$

Let $z \in [x]$ .

Then $||T^*[x]||=||Tz|| \le ||T||\cdot ||z||$,

hence $||T^*[x]||\le ||T||\cdot ||[x]||$.